# Network Error on Contact Search Results page change

Tags: contacts, error

To replicate, search all contacts, try to scroll to page 2
"Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

Reported by 2 clients, able to replicate.
Workaround is to use the 'glossary' of first letter of display name.
Pagination works fine after this.
Reverting to 'All' also reverts the problem

Replicated on CiviCRM v 5.11.0 and 5.12.0
Wordpress 5.1.1 and Drupal 7
Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.1.24, Apache

[image: Network Error]

Comment: It seems to be ok on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - can you check there and confirm?

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that I checked the demo too and it is fine.  But not on my clients's sites - replicated on 3 sites now, which have at least several thousand contacts.

Comment: We are suffering from a similar problem and the common factor seems to be contact search. There is no response to "export contacts" action when all radio button is chosen after a search is done on contacts. It just wouldn't export. I noticed there is something funny about the quick search console. There appears to be an error being raised. See the error log in the screenshot.[![See the error log in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqXQU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqXQU.png)

Comment: did anyone find an answer to this one as we have it when doing a contact search on a group. Can hit first page and last but not the intermediate pages or change the sort size.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] Yes found an answer with the help of the CiviCRM team - see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/963

The issue is MySQL configuration after upgrading, which adds ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to variable sql-mode.  There is a link to a patch but I found it straghtforward to remove this by adding the following line to my.cnf

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Hope that helps.